# Browser not getting launched with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to make WebDriver Instance universal. I have created a small Python file to instantiate the webDriver

Here is my code

```
#Driver.py
from selenium import webdriver

Instance = None

def Initialize():

    global Instance
    Instance = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\mystuff\\Browser\\chromedriver.exe")
    Instance.implicitly_wait(5)
    return Instance

def CloseDriver():

    global Instance
    Instance.quit()
```

---

This is being used in Commonfunctions.py

```
import Driver

class LoginPage:

    @staticmethod
    def GoToURL(url):
        print "In GoTo URL"
        Driver.Instance.get(url)
```

---

And Finally my Test File

```
import unittest
import Driver
from CommonFunctions import LoginPage


class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        Driver.Initialize()

    def testUserCanLogin(self):
        LoginPage.GoToURL("http://www.gmail.com")
```

When i try to execute this there is no error, I get the message "Process finished with exit(0) in the PyCharm console. However the browser is never launched.
If i try to do it in a single block then the browser gets launched smoothly.

I am trying to create a simple framework and this is my first step. If you have any other suggestions please guide me.

Thanks !!

Comment: have u installed gecko driver? try installing it. then it might work!

Comment: How are you running the test? what command did you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put following main in you test class,

```
class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        Driver.Initialize()

    def testUserCanLogin(self):
        LoginPage.GoToURL("http://www.gmail.com")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```